# Correct approach to machine learning model for robotics

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, robotics

i am looking for a starting point of which model or approach to use.
The case is the following:

A Robot with 9 inputs:

- -6 sensors which give a distance
- -Sensor that detects a crash
- -The current speed of left motor
- -the current speed of right motor

Output:
2 numbers (or 2 booleans) to control 2 motors (forward left and forward right)

Now i was thinking about letting a robot figure out his way to not crash.
I feed the 6 sensors along with one "that worked / did not work" as data into a model
Then a model gets trained to figure out that when a sensor value is below a certain number that a motor needs to be faster than the other one to avoid the crash input. Also, i need to tell the model that the crash flag needs to be avoided.

Now as platform i was thinking about a raspberry pi, propably with an azure connection, so i can use whatever model i want

But which model am i looking for? It needs to learn from continuous data. Try something, write that back, learn from it, and then try something else. Output propably needs to be multi-regression or multi-binary.

Input as well, multiple inputs. Needs to learn from a new data points already. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [reinforcment learning](https://pathmind.com/wiki/deep-reinforcement-learning). There is a lot of litterature on it concerning either robots or games AI. How does it work, well exactly like you said, continuously.

It(the **agent**) has an **environment**(sensors, current speeds) and he can perform **actions**(control motors) that will result on a reaction from the enviroment. With the given action it will receive a reward, like `distance from object < before`=> +1 else -1. You get the point. By trying, failing, it will create it's own **policy**(its behavior) that maximizes the reward.

The most used algorithm in reinforcment is **Q-Learning** (with its Deep Learning side called DQN).

Here is a paper that could be related to your problem : [link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8781522)